# I have a variable that outputs a string of dates, how can I change the format of all the dates in that string?

Tags: javascript, date

In JavaScript I have a variable that contains a series of dates all formatted like this:

```
5/3/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

How can I update that variable to change the format of the date to this:

```
May 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dates.map(d => d.toDateString().split(' ').slice(1, 3).join(' '))
```

Comment: Because `d.toDateString().substr(4,6)` is too easy? ;-)